# Replacing uniformly random numbers with evenly spaced numbers

Tags: distributions, sampling

If I want to statistically analyze the outcome of some friendly blackbox function $f(z + \epsilon)$ (e.g. standard errors or confidence intervals), where $\epsilon$ is a uniformly random error, is it a reasonable practice to replace random samples of the error with evenly spaced values $\epsilon \in \{\frac k N,  0 < k < N\}$? In Python terms, can I replace large samples of numpy.random.rand values with numpy.linspace values of equal size?

Does that practice have a name? Do sample statistics converge faster or slower than on actual random samples? I guess it generalizes to arbitrary univariate distributions by applying the inverse CDF to the gridded values, but what about multivariate distributions?

Comment: [Look into quasi-random numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuasirandomSequence.html).   You loose independence, so monte carlo algorithms using independence (and more than one random input) will not work.